# Is possible to increment(set) output library version using web deploy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webdeploy, assemblyversions

To deploy my web site, i'm simply right clicking on web project and selecting Publish(MS Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer).

Publish method: Web Deploy.

Is it possible, to increment version of assembly files automatically during deployment?

Thank you